# Python list comprehension vs for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have a bunch of class objects, "players". I get two different behaviors when I use a for loop vs LC...

**Python 2.7**

```
foo = something.blahObject
for i in foo:
    print i
```

Gives me what I want..

```
Object1
Object2
...
```

If I do

```
print [i for i in foo]
```

Gives me...

```
[<something.blahObject at 0x10af....>, <something.blahObject at 0x10f....>]
```

If a for loop and list comprehension behave similar why do I get different results? What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: List comprehension produces a separate list so is generally used when you want to apply some logic to each value in the original list. On the other hand, for loop in your case produces nothing besides printing out each value in the list named `foo`.

Comment: A Philips screwdriver and a slotted screwdriver are similar, but there's a reason any toolbox will contain (at least) one of each.

Comment: Also, `[i for i in foo]` is just `foo`.

Comment: it returns list of Object of your class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An object in a list will use its `__repr__` method, whereas an object printed by itself will use `__str__`. This is why you get different printouts when you use a `for` loop (will use `__str__`) and when you use list comprehension (will use `__repr__`).

```
class ExampleObject(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'ExampleRepresentation'

    def __str__(self):
        return 'ExampleString'

e = ExampleObject()
print e  # ExampleString
print [e]  # [ExampleRepresentation]
```

Comment: This is the most helpful of the answers, thanks! @Karin

Answer (score 0):

`print [i for i in mylist]` is functionally identical to `print mylist`, which prints the string representation of `mylist`, which means square brackets enclosing a comma-delimited listing of each element's string reproduction. If you loop over `mylist` and print each item separately with the `print` statement, it will go over the list and print the string representation of each of those items.

For more information, do some more research into lists and loops. I recommend the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/index.html).